# SELECT * FROM table where column like '%variable%' - multiple words in any order

Tags: php, mysql

I've written a quick search page for my colleagues using php where it queries the database. Their string is named $wordvariable (they also pick dates etc but that's not important here), here's what I'm doing so far:

```
$wordvariable = explode(" ", $wordvariable);
$wordvariable = implode("%", $wordvariable);
$Query = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE (column1 like '%$wordvariable%' or column2 like '%$wordvariable%')
    AND logdatex between $TimeEarlier and $TimeNow"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

however, this only searches for the words they type in the order they have typed them, e.g. searching "stack overflow" would find "stack this is overflow" but wouldn't find "overflow stack". I hope I've phrased this correctly, any help would be appreciated

Comment: By your example, if they searched "%Stack Overflow%", it would not find "Overflow Stack". They are nothing alike. If you intend to search by various words from a single input, you sould split the search up into seperate words first. That would get you a better result.

Comment: I know it won't find it, but it's help with finding it that I'm after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something LIKE this:

```
$where = "WHERE column1 LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR column1 LIKE '%", explode(" ", $wordvariable)) . "%'";
```

The short is, just `explode` the `$wordvariable` on spaces and then `implode` those individual words on the phrases that you want.

More verbose including `column2`:

```
$words  = explode(" ", $wordvariable);
$list1  = implode("%' OR column1 LIKE '%", $words);
$list2  = implode("%' OR column2 LIKE '%", $words);

echo $where = "WHERE (column1 LIKE '%$list1%') OR (column2 LIKE '%$list2%')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like here:

```
$wordvariable = explode(" ", $wordvariable);

$Query = mysql_query(
  "SELECT * FROM  table
   WHERE (column1 like '%" . implode("%' OR column1 Like '%", $wordvariable) . "%'
   OR column2 like '%" . implode("%' OR column2 Like '%", $wordvariable) . "%')
   AND logdatex between $TimeEarlier and $TimeNow"
) or die(mysql_error());
```